# Creating random colors with sample() is not good enough

Tags: r

I want create each loop in while loop create different color. I create, but this colors is similar. I want create more random color pick.
Now I create like this:

```
mycolor<-sample(colors(), 1)
```

I want change 1 with rnorm() and this not work. How else I can create random color?

Comment: `colors` holds a butt load of colors. You could try sampling from on of the `RColorBrewer` palettes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `rgb` function to create colours based on triplets of numeric values.

```
# sample three values in the range [0, 1]
samp <- runif(3)
# [1] 0.6095182 0.3291638 0.4417165

# create colour
do.call(rgb, as.list(samp))
# [1] "#9B5471"
```